# Angled slice in xarray

Tags: slice, angle, python-xarray

How can I create an angled slice of netcdf data in xarray? Lets say I have a netcdf file with vertical wind speed on a 100x100x100 grid. How would I go about if I wanted a vertical cross section of that data whose horizontal extent starts at [x,y]=[5,0] and ends at [95,100]. Is there an easy way in xarray where I could define a pivot point and an angle?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to find a elevation profile along a course not aligned with the dimensions. If you create a new dimension "along_course" and add the respective coordinates to it then it's possible to interpolate along the custom dimension. In your case with the extra altitude coordinates, I imagine if you used meshgrid to define the coordinates for x, y, z that may do the trick.

Here's what I did for a 2D case that you should be able to modify for your 3D case:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html#advanced-interpolation

```
startLat = 40.0
startLon = -80.0
endLat = 41.0
endLon = -79.0
n = 1000
x = xr.DataArray(np.linspace(startLon,endLon,n), dims='along_course')
y = xr.DataArray(np.linspace(startLat,endLat,n), dims='along_course')
elevation_profile = dataset['elevation'].interp(Lon=x, Lat=y, method='linear')
plt.plot(elevation_profile)
```

Comment: Also, I had a comment in my code that mentioned where this method came from in the xarray docs.
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html#advanced-interpolation

Comment: Thanks for your input! Very intersting, I was also able to plot a cross-sectional elevation profile with that, thank you! However I'm still struggling with 3D-ifying that. Doing dat = dataset['w'].interp(x=newx, y=newy, zw_3d=newz, method='nearest') seems to only get me a new 3d "cube" of data with just the new coordinates. How would I extract the cross section defined by startLon/lat and endLon/Lat?

Comment: See what I said about using meshgrid: "In your case with the extra altitude coordinates, I imagine if you used meshgrid to define the coordinates for x, y, z that may do the trick."

Meshgrid will allow constructing coordinates where for each x, y pair there will be a range of altitudes (z). I may try it out later.